# .net core project logout using ADFS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, oauth, oauth-2.0, adfs

I'm struggling with the logout method for ADFS authentication mechanism

This code doesn't really work

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
return RedirectToAction("login");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your logout url both in the app itself and in the Azure Portal.

You can follow along with the configurations in this Azure Sample to make sure everything is set correctly. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

(Take a look at the Accounts controller in particular. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs)

Based on your limited description this could be failing for a number of reasons.